# UITableView: Automatically scroll given row to top of screen OR to the bottom

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Let's say I have a list of 20 rows (á 44px). If I use this code:

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(item: 5, section: 0), at: UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: false)
```

the TableView is correctly scrolled so that the fifth row is at the top of the screen.

If I do the same for item `18`:

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(item: 18, section: 0), at: UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: false)
```

then the tableView also "correctly" scrolls so that the eighteenth row is stuck to the top of the screen - showing only rows 18, 19 and 20, and then a lot of space below row 20.

As soon as the user touches the tableView in any way, the content quickly snaps back so that row 20 touches the bottom of the screen. This state, where 20 is at the bottom, is what I want to happen in the first place. When I ask the tableView to scroll row 18 to the top of the screen, I want it to do it *only* if that is a natural scroll position for the tableView, or else just scroll to the bottom of the tableView.

The wanted/expected state works when using `animated:true`, but does not work when using `animated:false` - which I need to keep false (because I need the tableView to be scrolled to this position when the user enters this viewController).

Comment: Have you tried putting the code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`?

Comment: Where are you calling the tableView method currently?

Comment: @EmanH When the user enters the viewController, there is a spinner showing in the tableView, and a download starts. The download is normally completed before the push-transition is completed (within 0.1/0.2 sec), and the tableView updates immediately after download (though on UI-thread). This is, however, after viewDidLayoutSubviews (which does not call again when updating data). This happens even if I trigger it from a button click. I don't think it's a bug in my code or in the scroll-function, cause it's not actually "wrong" behaviour. Just not what I want. It does what it says it does.

Comment: @Sti I would recommend putting the code into `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and calling `setNeedsLayout` when the data has been loaded.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea.. I don't want the tableView to scroll to this position every single time the view lays out its subviews. I have more elements happening in this viewController which requires me to call setNeedsLayout. It feels wrong to have a boolean indicating if `tableViewShouldScrollOnNextLayoutSubview`..